# How to change my sprintf format string, based on size of long

Tags: c, printf, format-string

I would like to read in some `uint64_t` values from a hexadecimal string with `printf` and `scanf`.

Not all the platforms that I use have the same size for `long` or `long long`, so if I use a format string like `"%llx"` it gives warnings on platforms with a long long of 128 bits and `"%lx"` will give warnings on platforms with long long being 64 bits (and long smaller).

My first thought was to define the format string with a macro, but sizeof is not supported in macro expressions.

Is there a way to define my format string so that it will work on any platform, preferably without warnings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format string for `uint64_t` is defined by a macro `PRIu64`

For example:

```
uint64_t foo = 0;

printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", foo);
```

Similar format strings exist for `scanf`, in this case `SCNu64`.  These are macros defined in `<inttypes.h>`.